# Eigenvalues of covariance matrix are negative

Tags: python, statistics, pca

I'm working on the PCA of the mnist dataset, and I get a very strange result, I created a matrix whose rows are flattened mnist images, When I try to compute the eigenvalues of the covariance matrix, I get some negative values. But the covariance matrix is positive semi-definite.

```
np.linalg.eigvals(np.dot(mnistBis[:, 0:20].T, mnistBis[:, 0:20])) # mnistBis.shape=(60000, 784)
```

```
array([ 4.79599869e+02, -1.19628465e+02,  9.68398702e+01,  1.88726171e-01,
        0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00])
```

**Modification:**
Here is the full code

````
import tensorflow.keras.datasets.mnist as mnist
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
mnistBis = np.reshape(x_train, (-1, 28*28))
np.linalg.eigvalsh(np.dot(mnistBis[:, 0:20].T, mnistBis[:, 0:20]))

```
````

Comment: What is your input looking like? Do you have any missing values?
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/315297/negative-eigenvalues-in-principle-component-analysis-in-the-presence-of-missing

Comment: @NikosM. what do you mean? this is an array of eigenvalues.

Comment: yeap, misread it

Comment: @Sören what do you mean by missing values? np.dot(x.T, x) is a covariance matrix, I'd love to show the data, but I don't know how to show you a 60000x20 matrix

Comment: missing values are gaps in your dataset and may be the origin of the negative eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1):

That is probably a result of a floating point error.

The matrix is 60,000 x 20 and sparse (mostly zeros). The result of the calculations are values very close to zero that are not correctly represented by the computer.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using a generic eignvalue solver. Perhaps your matrix is badly conditioned and the aglorithm cannot pick it up. Lots of zero eigenvalues with few massive ones certainly seem suspicious. Have you tried solvers specific for hermitian/symmetric matricies? [eigh](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eigh.html%7C) & [eigvalsh](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eigvalsh.html#numpy.linalg.eigvalsh)

Also, I would z-score all your features, and drop all features with zero variance. This will set an upper bound on maximum possible eigenvalue since trace of your matrix will be the number of the features, and since positive definite matrix has only positive eigenvalues, the largest eigenvalue will be no larger than the trace.

Comment: eigvalsh gives me the same eigenvalues, in reverse order.

Comment: makes me think  something wrong with your matrix. if you subtract transpose from your matrix, do you get all zeros? is matrix real-valued? if you multiply the eigenvector with negative eigenvalue, do you get the negative eigenvalue? Small negative eigenvalues are ok - numerical errors. Large ones are strange

Comment: Better still,what are the eigenvalues of the symmetrized matrix? i.e. $\Re\left(A+A^T\right)/2$, where $A$ is the original matrix

Comment: I made a modification, see the full code to reproduce it.